# Toggle specific highcharts when checking/unchecking checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I have multiple scatter plots drawn using highcharts, and I have a list of checkboxes with labels corresponding to legend identifiers in highcharts, and I want to have functionality so that when I check/uncheck the box, it makes corresponding plot visible/hide dynamically. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Please describe your question more precisely. I suspect you need to make the legend item visible/hidden by checking/unchecking the box, am I right?

Comment: @daniel_s exactly

Comment: Sorry I have to rephrase the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement the functionality that you are expecting, you need to toggle `Series.showInLegend` flag using `Series.update()` function, on every `onchange` event on checkbox and also call on this series `setVisible()`  function to toggle its visibility on plot. Here is the example code of how to achieve it:

First you need to define the checkboxes similar to:

```
<input id="series1" type="checkbox" checked>Installation<br/>
<input id="series2" type="checkbox" checked>Manufacturing<br/>
<input id="series3"type="checkbox" checked>Sales and Distribution<br/>
```

Then itter on every of those checkboxes, and add an `onchange` event function to it. Inside this function you need to update appropriate series `showInLegend` value as I said above. You should be able to do that by checking presence of `legendItem` in series object. Take a look on code below:

```
var checkboxes = ['series1', 'series2', 'series3']

checkboxes.forEach((elem, i) => {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById(elem)
    checkbox.onchange = function() {

        chart.series[i].update({
            showInLegend: chart.series[i].legendItem ? false : true
        })
        chart.series[i].setVisible()

    }
})
```

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/uuwu48cm/

Comment: Sorry :( I wanted to make plot visible/hide. Unfortunately english is not my native language

Comment: What do you mean saying "plot"? Do you want to hide whole plotArea or just a series? Please specify your requirements more clarify.

Comment: I want to hide a series

Comment: I updated the answer above. Please take a look on it.